# Vue - Pinia Use Store Outside of Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, state-management, pinia

i want to use pinia store at test.js file. at test.js file i got socket codes.
here is my file structure

```
/src
 /stores
  mainStore.js
 App.vue
 main.js
 test.js
```

mainStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useMainStore = defineStore({
    id: 'main',
    state: () => ({
        foo: {},
    }),
    getters: {
        getFoo() {
            return this.foo
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setFoo(foo) {
            this.foo = foo
        }
    }
})
```

main.js

```
import { createApp, watch } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.use(router)

// reload page proof, persist store
if (localStorage.getItem('state')) {
    pinia.state.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
}

watch(() => pinia.state, (state) => {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state.value))
}, { deep: true })

app.mount('#app')

export { app }
```

test.js

```
import { useMainStore } from './stores/mainStore'

const store = useMainStore()
```

then i got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRBJM.png)

```
Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
```

on internet search i tried:
stores/create_pinia.js

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
const pinia = createPinia()
export default pinia
```

test.js

```
import pinia from './stores/pinia_create'
import { useMainStore } from './stores/mainStore.js'
const store = useMainStore(pinia)
```

it works but then i got 2 stores. quick example

some_vue_file.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
  <-- lets assume store.foo is LOREM -->
  {{ store.foo }}.   <-- renders LOREM -->
 </div>
</template>
<script setup>
// import...
// use store...
</script>
```

test.js

```
import pinia from './stores/pinia_create'
import { useMainStore } from './stores/mainStore.js'
const store = useMainStore(pinia)
console.log(store.foo)   // writes on console an empty object, {}.
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say, but try reading this https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.js

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

const pinia = createPinia()

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)

//...
```

Replace to

```js
import pinia from './stores/pinia_create'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)

// move to stores/create_pinia.js
// reload page proof, persist store
//if (localStorage.getItem('state')) {
//    pinia.state.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
//}

// ...
```

stores/create_pinia.js

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
const pinia = createPinia()

// reload page proof, persist store
if (localStorage.getItem('state')) {
    pinia.state.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
}
export default pinia
```